# add to list without bringing whole list into memory

Tags: java, list

I have a web service that holds information for users. Each user has a list of items, possibly thousands. I want to add an item to the list without loading the entire list. Is there a list implementation that allows you to add elements to the list without bringing the entire list into memory?

Comment: Where is the list ? In a file ?

Comment: Well where is the list, if it's not in memory? What kind of list is it? Who are the overlords of the UFO?

Comment: This question doesn't really make sense.  How do you add to something that doesn't exist?  Where does this List exist?  In a file?

Comment: the list is on a remote database.

Answer (score 1):

A Doubly Linked List.  By definition it's not necessary to traverse the list to add something to the end since it contains a pointer to the end.

Comment: After reading the other answer, I think maybe I was being too abstract in my answer.  On the other hand, maybe that's what you wanted...

Comment: He asked about the memory footprint, not about the speed.  Any and all in-memory list are, well.. in-memory..

Comment: Yes, all in memory lists are ... in memory.  You are right.

What I was saying was, if you have a not-in-memory list (in a file, in a DB, don't care, etc) then the way to add to the end would be to have a "pointer" to the end.  When I said it's not necessary to traverse the list, I didn't mean you'd save time, I meant you don't need those items in memory.

Answer (score 1):

> the list is on a remote database. –
>   Lumpy

So the list is in a database, so it's not really a Java List?  It's just a bunch of database rows?  In that case why not just do an insert into the database to add another row?

Answer (score 1):

Lazy proxies. You can use a JDK dynamic proxy ([`java.lang.reflect.Proxy`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html)) where you store only the information needed for retrieving the items from the database, not the items themselves. Only when calling the `get(..)`, `size()`, `contains(..)` methods - fetch the data.

However I have a feeling that you are doing things the wrong way. Give more details about your implementation.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO list VALUES 1, 2, 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

None that I know.
With middlewares such as Terracotta, some collections (such as maps) can be loaded on-demand and partially, but this doesn't exist as-is in the standart JDK.